# Why does akka http not continue requesting?

Tags: request, connection, akka, akka-http

I've got an issue with akka-http. I'm trying to request several times in a flow but it stops with default configuration at 4 times. Here is the code I use. Can someone help me understanding why it waits?

Thanks a lot

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http.{HostConnectionPool, OutgoingConnection}
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{HttpRequest, HttpResponse}
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Try, Failure, Success}

object TestHttp extends LazyLogging {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    import system.dispatcher
    val decider: Supervision.Decider = {
      case e => {
        logger.error(e.getMessage, e)
        Supervision.Resume
      }
    }
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer(ActorMaterializerSettings(system).withSupervisionStrategy(decider).withDebugLogging(true))
    val resultSink: Sink[(Try[HttpResponse], Int), Future[Unit]] = Sink.foreach { case (hr, i) => {
      hr match {
        case Success(r) => logger.info(s"Success ${r} for ${i}")
        case Failure(e) => logger.error(s"Error ${e} for ${i}")
      }
    }
    }
    val source: Source[Int, Unit] = Source(0 to 1500).map(i => {
      logger.info(s"${i} iteration")
      i
    })

    val buildHr: Flow[Int, (HttpRequest, Int), Unit] = Flow[Int].map { case s => {
      (HttpRequest(uri = "/").withDefaultHeaders(), s)
    }
    }

    val connection: Flow[(HttpRequest, Int), (Try[HttpResponse], Int), HostConnectionPool] = Http().cachedHostConnectionPool("www.adajam.uk.com")
    import FlowGraph.Implicits._
    source.via(buildHr).via(connection).to(resultSink).run()
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to read the response bodies, i.e. do something with `r.entity.dataBytes`. Otherwise, the connection cannot be reused.

Comment: Thanks jrudolph, it works. After reading the entity, the flow continues and releases the connection.

Comment: Cool, glad it works! :)

Comment: Could you please post your own answer and accept it ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to release the connection, the body has to be read.
This can be done with

```
r.entity.dataBytes.to(Sink.ignore)
```